401 Not authorized - Problem accessing a Fiori application
I have always been able to access one of our apps from our client 910 via a Fiori Launchpad without any problems.
However, presumably without anyone having made any changes in the backend or system, a new prompt suddenly appears after clicking on the app. Here I am asked to log in again:

I cannot log in here with the user I am currently using in the system. If I try, the prompt simply re-renders and is blank again.
When I click on Cancel, a message appears with the message:

401 not authorized.


Now comes the really interesting part. When I log in to this prompt with the client 810 (which doesn't even have access to the app normally), the app opens normally.
It seems that the app requires a cookie with an 810 client. Although the app usually always ran without any problems if you were in the system with the client 910.
